# Find a function so that for integer $k>1$ and $\lambda>0$: $ \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} h(t) \frac{e^{-n\lambda}(n\lambda)^t}{t!}=\lambda^k, $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, statistics, poisson-distribution, parameter-estimation

If I want to find a function $h(\cdot): \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ so that for integer $k>1$ and $\lambda>0$:
$$
\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} h(t) \frac{e^{-n\lambda}(n\lambda)^t}{t!}=\lambda^k, 
$$

The answer is that $h(t)=t(t-1)\cdots (t-k+1)/n^k$. But I have no idea how to get this and I got a different result: note that this is same as

$$
\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} h(t)\lambda^{-k} \frac{e^{-n\lambda}(n\lambda)^t}{t!}=1
$$

Since we have
$$
\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-n\lambda}(n\lambda)^t}{t!}=1,
$$
then we can just take
$$
h(t)\lambda^{-k}=1
$$
That means $h(t)=\lambda^k$... Where am I wrong?

Comment: $$
\lambda ^k {\rm e}^{n\lambda }  = \frac{{{\rm d}^k {\rm e}^{n\lambda } }}{{{\rm d}n^k }} = \frac{{{\rm d}^k }}{{{\rm d}n^k }}\sum\limits_{t = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{(n\lambda )^t }}{{t!}}}  = \sum\limits_{t = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{\rm d}^k }}{{{\rm d}n^k }}\frac{{(n\lambda )^t }}{{t!}}}  = \sum\limits_{t = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{t(t - 1) \cdots (t - k + 1)}}{{n^k }}\frac{{(n\lambda )^t }}{{t!}}} 
$$

Comment: Then $$
\sum\limits_{t = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{t(t - 1) \cdots (t - k + 1)}}{{n^k }}\frac{{(n\lambda )^t }}{{t!}}}  = \lambda ^k \sum\limits_{t = k}^\infty  {\frac{{(n\lambda )^{t - k} }}{{(t - k)!}}}  = \sum\limits_{t = 0}^\infty  {\lambda ^k \frac{{(n\lambda )^t }}{{t!}}} 
$$

Comment: The  set of acceptable $h$ is enormous and you have exhibited two simple examples....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} h(t) \frac{e^{-n\lambda}(n\lambda)^t}{t!}=\lambda^k$$

Or, $$\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \frac{h(t) n^t}{t!}\lambda^t=\color{blue}{e^{n\lambda}}\lambda^k=\color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(n\lambda)^j}{j!}}\lambda^k=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{n^j}{j!}\lambda^{j+k}$$

That is,

$$\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \frac{h(t) n^t}{t!}\lambda^t=\sum_{t=k}^\infty \frac{n^{t-k}}{(t-k)!}\lambda^t$$

Comparing coefficients of $\lambda^t$ on both sides, you get

$$h(t)=\begin{cases}
\frac{t!}{n^t}\cdot\frac{n^{t-k}}{(t-k)!}&,\text{ if }t\ge k 
\\ 0 &,\text{ else }
\end{cases}$$

Or,

$$h(t)=\frac{t!}{n^k(t-k)!}\mathbf1_{\{t\ge k\}}=\frac{t(t-1)(t-2)\cdots(t-k+1)}{n^k}\mathbf1_{\{t\ge k\}}$$

This is just one way of finding the best unbiased estimator of $\lambda^k$ when $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d $\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$. There are other ways of course, like using the Rao-Blackwell theorem.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1794929?rq=1